# "BAD Could not parse command" is returned if mailbox name contains non-English symbols

Tags: imap, chilkat

I'm using Chilkat.IMAP components to get emails from IMAP servers. If a mailbox name contains non-English symbols, "BAD Could not parse command" is returned:

```
----IMAP REQUEST----
aaai LIST "[Gmail]/" "%"
----IMAP RESPONSE----
* LIST (\All \HasNoChildren) "/" "[Gmail]/All Mail"
* LIST (\HasChildren \Trash) "/" "[Gmail]/Bin"
* LIST (\Drafts \HasNoChildren) "/" "[Gmail]/Drafts"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Important) "/" "[Gmail]/Important"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Sent) "/" "[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Junk) "/" "[Gmail]/Spam"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "[Gmail]/&BB8EMAQ,BDoEMA-"
aaai OK Success

----IMAP REQUEST----
aaaj LIST "[Gmail]/All Mail/" "%"
----IMAP RESPONSE----
aaaj OK Success

----IMAP REQUEST----
aaap LIST "[Gmail]/Папка/" "%"
----IMAP RESPONSE----
aaap BAD Could not parse command
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMAP by default does not send 8-bit characters, and the original protocol defines mailboxes with non-English ASCII characters to be UTF-7 encoded (with some modifications).  This is the `&BB8EMAQ,BDoEMA-` you're seeing.

You can either add UTF-7 encoding/decoding to your application, or, if your server is new enough, `ENABLE` UTF-8 mode.  Note: enabling UTF-8 may get you Unicode in places you do not expect.  Gmail does support this extension.

```
> a LIST "" *
< ...
< * LIST (\HasChildren) "/" "&AOk-cole"

> b ENABLE UTF8=ACCEPT
< ...
< * LIST (\HasChildren) "/" "école"
```

Here's how that UTF-7 string breaks down:

```
[Gmail]/&BB8EMAQ,BDoEMA-
```

& and - shift in and out of decoding mode, so this looks like

```
"[Gmail]/" + mUTF7decode("BB8EMAQ,BDoEMA")
```

And here's a python 3 one liner that decodes that.  With "===" added to meet the base64 padding requirements, and the `altchars` specifying the last two characters of the base64 encoding:

```
>>> import base64;  base64.b64decode("BB8EMAQ,BDoEMA===", altchars="+,").decode("utf-16be")
'Папка'
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this approach. I just wonder why Chilkat component converts "[Gmail]/&BB8EMAQ,BDoEMA-" to "[Gmail]/Папка/" in the response and doesn't convert this in a request.

Comment: According to RFC-5738, will "aaap LIST *"[Gmail]/Папка/" "%" work right?
Please note there is * followed by mailbox name in double quotes.

Comment: If you've used `ENABLE UTF8=ACCEPT`, yes.  Your library should have a function for doing the necessary conversion, or giving you the raw mailbox name  rather than the decoded display name.

Comment: It seems, ENABLE UTF8=ACCEPT is not required if a client uses utf8-quoted strings in requests only. In other words, if an IMAP server has a capability "UTF8=ACCEPT", a client can send utf8-quoted strings. The server should send UTF-7 until ENABLE UTF8=ACCEPT is sent.

Comment: That appears not to be true for gmail.  They don't actually support the *"utf8string" syntax, but they do support UTF-8 in regular "strings", but for folders, only after ENABLE.  Eg, they've only implemented about 10% of the RFC.

Comment: I've used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51379904/5433922) to encode mailbox name to modified UTF-7 - works fine. Please note a little fix is required at the code. I left a comment there.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you're using a very old version of Chilkat.  Try the latest version, it should work fine.  If not, please let us know..

Comment: The latest version (9.5.0.75) has the same issue:

 ListMailboxes(530ms):
  DllDate: Aug 25 2018
  ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.75
  UnlockPrefix: Start my 30-day Trial
  Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
  Language: .NET 4.0
 ...
    ImapCmdSent: aaap LIST "[Gmail]/Папка/" "%"
    getCompleteResponse(530ms):
   ImapCmdResp: aaap BAD Could not parse command
    --getCompleteResponse
    isOK:
   serverResponse: aaap BAD Could not parse command
    --isOK
    Failed.
  --listMailboxes
  Failed.
   --ListMailboxes

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? If not, I know for a fact that my [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) .NET library works correctly in this situation.